# React props vs children. What to use when?

Tags: reactjs

What is the difference between the two approaches ?

Passing text for a button as props

```
<TextComponent title="Save"/>

function TextComponent(props){
  return <button>{props.title}<button/>
}
```

vs

Passing text as a child

```
<TextComponent>Save<TextComponent />

function TextComponent(props){
  return <button>{props.children}<button/>      
}
```

Comment: @skyboyer you are right, my bad

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`children` prop is something that you use when the structure of what needs to be rendered within the child component is not fixed and is controlled by the component which renders it.

However if behaviour of the component is consistent across all its renders it can define the specific props that it needs and the parent can pass them to it.

A very simple example could be a `Navbar` which can use `children`. For a `Navbar` the items that it needs to render as well as the order or alignment or items  depends on how it needs to be used at different instances or across different pages. For instance `Navbar` somewhere can have Search component at one place and at some other place not have it. Also the menus may sometimes be needed to the left followed by Login menu item to the right and a searchbar between them and sometimes they may all be present to the right without the searchbar. In such cases the parent component can control how the internal structure would be

Answer (score 9):

You should use `children` when you don't know them ahead of time, see: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Here, if you KNOW that you'll use a title inside your child component, just use a named prop.

I'd say that if you ask yourself the question: "Ok, but what will that generic component render?" is when you should use `children`

Answer (score 3):

You use `props.children` on a component which acts as a container and does not know about their children ahead of time.

Basically `props.children` it is used to display whatever you include between the opening and closing tags of the "containing" component when invoking it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the React official docs:

> Some components don’t know their children ahead of time. This is especially common for components like Sidebar or Dialog that represent generic “boxes”.
>
> We recommend that such components use the special **children** prop to pass children elements directly into their output:

Simply put, it `props.children` just displays whatever is put between the opening and closing tags.

As asked in your question, there is **not** much difference in the use case specified by you.

But, say you had a small left icon the component  then passing 'title' as a separate prop would make more sense Eg.

```
<TextComponent title="Save" src="https://..." />
```

```
function TextComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={props.src}/>
      <button>{props.title}<button/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do know what your props are, use props. Otherwise, use children (aka [containment](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)).

Other than that, using props/children in your case depends on what you want to pass:

1. If its a single props (like `item`), than it doesn't matter which method you'll choose.
2. Else, you should check what you are passing inside `children` as you might pass other values which you don't want to render.

**I would suggest using the selective approach (e.g `props.title`), since you are always aware of whats going inside your components.**

Answer (score 0):

Pedantically said, when I pass something that is a child I use children, and when I pass a property I use a prop. Here is an example.

```
const LoginForm = () => {
  // use hooks for form state
  return (
    <SomeForm>
      <UserNameTextField />
      <PassWordField />
    </SomeForm>
  )
```

I now want to add a forgot-password button, which I choose to define as a child for `LoginForm`.

- I don't want to add this to the JSX inside `LoginForm`, because the button does not relate to the component state at all.
- I do not want to add it as a component prop, because a forgot-password button is not a property of a form. (It's not a `onSubmit` callback, nor a bit of styling, nor something that adjusts the form aspect of `LoginForm`.)

Therefore, I use a child.

```
const LoginForm<{ children?: { forgotPasswordButton: ReactNode }}> = ({ children }) => {
  // same as before
  return (
  // ..
      <PasswordField />
      {children?.forgotPasswordButton}
    </SomeForm>
```